# After pg_restore, an error; PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have just done the pg_restore in my local db with the heroku downloaded db (last.dump). And now I have an error;  PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied.
I'have added the username and password in database.yml but nothing.
What must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved adding 'username: postgres' and 'password: ***' in the general config part of database.yml;

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: postgres
  password: ***
```

Not in the development part;

```
 development:
  <<: *default
  database: CigBackCount_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: CigBackCount

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:
```

After the changes I have reload the DB;

```
pg_ctl reload
```